# Manually copy MySQL 5.5 database to a different computer

Tags: mysql

My company uses a product that uses MySQL 5.5 for its backend database. The product automatically installs and configures MySQL during it's installation process. The product can be configured to run in a Hot Standby Redundant configuration. In these cases, the same installation process is performed on 2 separate servers and then during the products initial configuration redundant mode is selected. The product internally handles all the processes of duplicating the database data and keeping the 2 databases in sync. MySQL has know knowledge of the redundant setup. The MySQL installation on both server are identical, same location and same structure. The product does not have a very elegant/efficient way to sync a large, say 300G is size with 3K tables, database from the Primary server to the Backup server in cases where this is required, such as when creating a redundant system from a Single/Primary server config that has already been running for a while. My question is as follows.

Is there a safe/supported way to just manually copy the database/files from the Primary server to the Backup server considering that the MySQL installation on both servers are identical? BTW, this is on Production Windows Servers. I know I can do a full Export of the database from the Primary and then Import it on the BU server, but this can take hours. I am hoping there is a faster supported way to just copy the files from one server to the other, but in researching this I see conflicting info.

System Info
Windows
MySQL 5.5
Identical installation on both servers
"C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data"
Innodb
File per table = true

Thanks in advance for any advice.

I once tried to just copy the Database Folder that contains all the innodb table files,  "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\Mydbase", from one server to another but mysql would not start up and had errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: shut down the MySQL Server service on both computers. Then you can move the files in the datadir in any way you want. But this incurs some downtime while you do the file transfer.

If you must have no downtime, it's also possible, but requires more steps.

What I do is use Percona XtraBackup to make a physical backup of the source instance, but this won't work as easily for you because you are on Windows. XtraBackup doesn't work on Windows. Some people use tricks to [run XtraBackup in a Docker container on Windows](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/03/20/running-percona-xtrabackup-windows-docker/).

Then restore the XtraBackup to your new computer in the normal way, and configure it as a replica of the source instance. See https://docs.percona.com/percona-xtrabackup/8.0/howtos/setting_up_replication.html

By making the new instance a replica, you can let it get updated with the most recent changes that have occurred on the source instance while you were setting up the replica.

Then at some point you decide to switch to the new instance. Then you set the source instance to read-only mode, to prevent client applications from making any new changes. Let the replica catch up with the last final changes (this should only take a second if the replica was keeping up with changes already). Now you can change your client applications to use the replica instead of the former source. Then un-configure replication on the new instance with RESET SLAVE because the last thing you want is for any more changes to occur on the former source and replicate to the new instance.

If you try this procedure, I suggest you test it on a test instance — NOT your production instance — until you are comfortable with the tools.

P.S.: In addition to not supporting Windows, I have no idea if the current version of XtraBackup works with MySQL 5.5. That version was released in 2010, and reached its end of life in 2018. So I think you will need to research which version of XtraBackup still can read a MySQL 5.5 instance. You might have to use an old version of XtraBackup.

Comment: Thanks for your response. A clarification question:  Would I copy the entire ""C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\"" folder including the idbdata1 and logfile0 and 1 files, or just the child folder that contains all the innodb tables/files for the product's actual database? This is where I get confused because the "data" folder contains folders for all databases but only one "ibdata1" file which if I understand it correctly contains info for all innodb databases. Thanks again.

Comment: You need all the files together. The iblogfiles might not be needed if you perform a clean shutdown, but they're probably not large compared to the rest of the dataset, so why not copy them too. The ibdata1 contains some metadata for your tablespaces, so it's definitely required. It might also contain parts of your data that haven't been merged into the .ibd files yet, even if you had done a clean shutdown. Also there are necessary system tables under the `mysql` schema subdirectory. Just copy the whole data folder and everything under it.

Comment: Thank you again very much. I will do some testing and report back if I run into any issues. Happy holidays

Comment: I noticed that the .err and .pid files have the server name embedded in the file name which these files will have different names on the 2 servers. If I copy and move the entire "data" folder to the destination server it will have the wrong file names. will this possibly cause issues or will MySQL just create new files using the current server name  when started back up? Thanks again.

Comment: I expect the MySQL Server will create new files according to the hostname of the new server.